# Erro ao consumir Web Service axml com apache cordova Visual studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, visual-studio, apache-cordova

Pessoal tenho um projeto com o apache cordova rodando no visual studio, quando tento fazer uma conexão web service me retorna o erro abaixo

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined at ChildScope.Teste [as WS]
>   (controllers.js:15) at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643),
>   :4:197) at ionic.bundle.js:65429 at ChildScope.$eval
>   (ionic.bundle.js:30400) at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
>   at HTMLAnchorElement. (ionic.bundle.js:65428) at defaultHandlerWrapper
>   (ionic.bundle.js:16792) at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler
>   (ionic.bundle.js:16780) at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953) at
>   tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2942) (anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:26799
>   (anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:23512 $apply @ ionic.bundle.js:30505
>   (anonymous) @ ionic.bundle.js:65428 defaultHandlerWrapper @
>   ionic.bundle.js:16792 eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:16780
>   triggerMouseEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:2953 tapClick @
>   ionic.bundle.js:2942 tapTouchEnd @ ionic.bundle.js:3069
>   _simulateTouchEvent @ ripple.js:47 _translateMouseEvent @ ripple.js:47

Codigo JS e HTML

```js
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
  
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPopup)
{     
    $scope.WS = function Teste() {
        var webserUrl = "http://example/service.asmx";
        var soapRequest =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
                <soap:Body> \
                <ListarTodosPlanosMarbeg xmlns="http://www.example.com.br" /> \
                </soap:Body> \
                </soap:Envelope>';        
        
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: webserUrl,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapRequest,
                success: SuccessOccur,
                error: ErrorOccur
            });
       
    };
    function SuccessOccur(data, status, req) {
        if (status == "success")
            alert(req.responseText);
    }
    function ErrorOccur(data, status, req) {
        alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
    }
})
```

```html
<ion-view title="Login" id="page1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
  <ion-content padding="true" scroll="false" class="has-header" ng-controller="loginCtrl">    
      <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>      
    <div>
      <img src="img/i1ttvhpETnaA7fesSv1p_LogoGebram.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    </div>
    <div id="login-markdown2" style="text-align:center;" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
      <p style="color:#000000;">
        <strong>Login</strong>
      </p>
    </div>      
    <form id="login-form4" class="list">
      <label class="item item-input" id="login-input5">
        <input type="text" placeholder="CPF/CNPJ" ng-model="CPF_CNPJ">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input" id="login-input6">
        <input type="text" placeholder="SENHA" ng-model="Senha">
      </label>
    </form>
    <a id="login-button1" class="button button-positive  button-block" ng-click="WS()">OK</a>    
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>        
    
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <style type="text/css">
      .platform-ios .manual-ios-statusbar-padding{
        padding-top:20px;
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding{
        padding-top:0px; 
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding .scroll{
        padding-top:0px !important;
      }
      ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth {
        margin-left:-10px;
        margin-right:-10px;
      }
      ion-list.manual-list-fullwidth div.list > .item, .list.card.manual-card-fullwidth > .item {
        border-radius:0px;
        border-left:0px;
        border-right: 0px;
      }
      .show-list-numbers-and-dots ul{
        list-style-type: disc;
        padding-left:40px;
      }
      .show-list-numbers-and-dots ol{
        list-style-type: decimal;
        padding-left:40px;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
     
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
     
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Only required for Tab projects w/ pages in multiple tabs 
    <script src="lib/ionicuirouter/ionicUIRouter.js"></script>
    -->

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
          <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você incluiu a lib `jquery` no projeto? De acordo com o erro, não está definido: $ is not defined at ChildScope.

Comment: sim esta incluido, tenho que fazer alguma referencia dele na parte do javascript? me desculpe as perguntas , sou novo nessa parte

Comment: adicionei o print da solution onde está a jquery

Comment: Ok, ele existe na pasta, mas está a ser incluído no index ou dentro do seu template? É que o controlador faz referência ao `jquery` mas pelo que percebi a lib está sendo incluída dentro do seu template. Retire e adicione no index: `<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>`

Comment: eu retirei do template e inclui no index.html (como adicionei o codigo a cima), mas continua o mesmo erro

Comment: criei um novo projeto e esse erro não apareceu, mas apareceu o seguinte: index.html:46 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.